# Como inserir valores nulos numa lista de dados?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Acredito que o problema seja aqui:

`'tlkc_conversation_2' => '',`

Estou tentando inserir dados no banco, porém alguns campos são nulos, e estou recebendo a 
seguinte mensagem:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value
>   list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value
>   count at row 3 (SQL: insert into `talk_conversation` (`tlk_id`,
>   `tlkc_conversation_1`, `tlkc_conversation_2`, `tlkc_created`,
>   `tlkc_order`, `tlkc_person_1`, `tlkc_user_option`) values (34, Olá!
>   Nesta semana vamos falar um pouquinho sobre pandemias e tentar
>   entender um pouco melhor o que estamos vivendo no mundo de hoje. Como
>   você sabe, estamos passando por uma situação incomum, causada pelo
>   coronavírus.  Esse vírus surgiu na China, em dezembro de 2019, e, em
>   março de 2020, a doença causada por ele, chamada de COVID-19, foi
>   considerada uma pandemia pela Organização Mundial da Saúde (OMS). A
>   transmissão da doença ocorre pelo ar ou por contato com secreções
>   contaminadas, como espirro, tosse e catarro., Sim, isso eu sei. O que
>   eu não sei é o que geralmente muda com essa nova classificação...,
>   2020-04-27 10:50:31, 1, 12, 2), (34, Vamos lá. É legal lembrar que uma
>   pandemia está longe de parecer algo sem controle. Também não significa
>   que nesse caso as medidas tomadas são ineficientes, ou ainda que não
>   há mais o que fazer. Uma pandemia é definida quando uma doença
>   infecciosa se propaga e atinge simultaneamente um grande número de
>   pessoas em todo o mundo! É isso o que a determina., Ah, entendi! Então
>   quer dizer que o fato de uma doença se tornar uma pandemia não
>   significa que muda a forma de ela se proliferar e de nós nos
>   cuidarmos, certo?, 2020-04-27 10:50:31, 2, 12, 2), (34, Exatamente!
>   Devemos sempre lembrar que todos nós integramos a humanidade, e, pelo
>   fato de a doença ser de alcance global, é importante pensar
>   coletivamente para frear o avanço dos contágios. Tendo isso em mente,
>   você tem um desafio pela frente: ler três textos, responder ao Quiz e
>   desvendar o mistério desta semana. Bom trabalho!, 2020-04-27 10:50:31,
>   3, 12, 2))

```
  $id_background_dialog_1 = 34;

   $person_1 = 12;
   $person_2 = null;

  $fase1 = [
             [
                 'tlk_id' => $id_background_dialog_1, 
                 'tlkc_order' => 1, 
                 'tlkc_conversation_1' => 'Olá! Nesta semana vamos falar um pouquinho sobre pandemias e tentar entender um pouco melhor o que estamos vivendo no mundo de hoje. Como você sabe, estamos passando por uma situação incomum, causada pelo coronavírus.  Esse vírus surgiu na China, em dezembro de 2019, e, em março de 2020, a doença causada por ele, chamada de COVID-19, foi considerada uma pandemia pela Organização Mundial da Saúde (OMS). A transmissão da doença ocorre pelo ar ou por contato com secreções contaminadas, como espirro, tosse e catarro.', 
                 'tlkc_conversation_2' => 'Sim, isso eu sei. O que eu não sei é o que geralmente muda com essa nova classificação...', 
                 'tlkc_person_1' => $person_1, 
                 'tlkc_person_2' => $person_2, 
                 'tlkc_created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
                 'tlkc_updated' => null, 
                 'tlkc_timeout_1' => null, 
                 'tlkc_timeout_2' => null, 
                 'tlkc_picture_1' => null,
                 'tlkc_picture_2' => null, 
                 'tlkc_user_option' => 2
             ],
             [
                 'tlk_id' => $id_background_dialog_1, 
                 'tlkc_order' => 2, 
                 'tlkc_conversation_1' => 'Vamos lá. É legal lembrar que uma pandemia está longe de parecer algo sem controle. Também não significa que nesse caso as medidas tomadas são ineficientes, ou ainda que não há mais o que fazer. Uma pandemia é definida quando uma doença infecciosa se propaga e atinge simultaneamente um grande número de pessoas em todo o mundo! É isso o que a determina.', 
                 'tlkc_conversation_2' => 'Ah, entendi! Então quer dizer que o fato de uma doença se tornar uma pandemia não significa que muda a forma de ela se proliferar e de nós nos cuidarmos, certo?', 
                 'tlkc_person_1' => $person_1, 
                 'tlkc_person_2' => $person_2, 
                 'tlkc_created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
                 'tlkc_updated' => null, 
                 'tlkc_timeout_1' => null, 
                 'tlkc_timeout_2' => null, 
                 'tlkc_picture_1' => null,
                 'tlkc_picture_2' => null, 
                 'tlkc_user_option' => 2
             ],
             [
                 'tlk_id' => $id_background_dialog_1, 
                 'tlkc_order' => 3, 
                 'tlkc_conversation_1' => 'Exatamente! Devemos sempre lembrar que todos nós integramos a humanidade, e, pelo fato de a doença ser de alcance global, é importante pensar coletivamente para frear o avanço dos contágios. Tendo isso em mente, você tem um desafio pela frente: ler três textos, responder ao Quiz e desvendar o mistério desta semana. Bom trabalho!', 
                 'tlkc_conversation_2' => '', 
                 'tlkc_person_1' => $person_1, 
                 'tlkc_person_2' => $person_2, 
                 'tlkc_created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
                 'tlkc_updated' => null, 
                 'tlkc_timeout_1' => null, 
                 'tlkc_timeout_2' => null, 
                 'tlkc_picture_1' => null,
                 'tlkc_picture_2' => null, 
                 'tlkc_user_option' => 2
             ]
         ];

 DB::table('talk_conversation')->insert(
             $fase1
         );
```

**Tabela:**

```
CREATE TABLE `talk_conversation` (
  `tlkc_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tlk_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tlkc_order` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tlkc_conversation_1` text,
  `tlkc_conversation_2` text,
  `tlkc_person_1` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tlkc_person_2` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tlkc_created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `tlkc_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `tlkc_timeout_1` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tlkc_timeout_2` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tlkc_picture_1` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tlkc_picture_2` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tlkc_user_option` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tlkc_id`),
  KEY `talk_id_idx` (`tlk_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Se seu campo já está NULL no banco, basta você retirar do array os campos que quer que sejam nulos ( os q estão com "=> NULL" ), que o Eloquent vai montar a query sem eles e o banco preenche com NULL.

Veja este exemplo:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/insert-null-value-with-query-builder

Comment: Então, mas eu fiz um método que faz isso, veja neste exemplo:https://ideone.com/yHytJc, mas mesmo assim deu erro, quando eu quero preencher campo vazio, sem ser nulo, como faço?

Comment: Vou tentar te explicar: NULL é um tipo de registro, VAZIO são vários tipos de registro. NULL faz parte dos registros de VAZIO, mas os outros tipos de registo VAZIO são diferentes de NULL. O valor NULL não precisa de dados para representá-lo na memória, mas "", 0 , FALSE .... todos os outros precisam. 

Você pode utilizar no seu if:
1. EMPTY($data[$this->key]) para testar se é vazio ( isto inclui testar 0, FALSE, "", NULL....)
2. IS_NULL($data[$this->key]) para testar se ele é apenas NULL.